# How to solve the python cheerleader problem?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, design-patterns

So, I am trying to solve this problem:

Write a function named cheerleader that accepts two integer parameters lines and cheers and prints a series of "cheer" lines at increasing levels of indentation. The first parameter represents the number of lines of output to print, and the second represents the number of "cheers" per line. For example, the call of cheerleader(2, 4) means that you should print 2 lines of output, each containing 4 "cheers." A "cheer" is an occurrence of the word "Go" in the output. Neighboring cheers are separated by the word "Team", so 1 cheer is printed as "Go", 2 cheers as "Go Team Go", 3 cheers are printed as "Go Team Go Team Go", and so on.

The lines you print should be displayed at increasing levels of indentation. The first line displayed should have no indentation, but each following line should be intended by 3 spaces more than the one before it. In other words, the 2nd line of output should be indented by 3 spaces, the 3rd line by 6 spaces, and so on. You may assume that both parameters passed your function will have values of at least 1. Please find picture for output expectations:

[image]

This is my solution so far:

```
    for i in range(1 , n+1):
        for j in range(0, i):
            if j == i-1:
                for k in range (0, m-1):
                        print("Go" , end=" ")
                        print("Team" , end=" ")
                if k == m-2:
                    print("Go" , end=" ")
            else:
                print('   ', end='')
        print()
```

I am unable to satisfy all the conditions though. Please help

Comment: Hint: look up the string `join` function.

Comment: It's as simple as using an `print("    "*i + " Team ".join(["Go"] * b))` where i is the ith iteration of the number of lines and b is the number of Go's per line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of printing each word individually, first build the string and then print it `lines` times

```py
def cheerleader(lines, cheers):
    string_to_print = ''
    for line in range(lines):
        for cheer in range(cheers):
            if cheer == 0:
                string_to_print = '   ' * line
                string_to_print = f'{string_to_print}Go'
            else:
                string_to_print = f'{string_to_print} Team Go'
        print(string_to_print)
```